# Consulta em Tabelas Relacionadas | Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Tenho o seguinte relacionamento em um sistema de teste que estou fazendo.

:: MODEL EMPLOYEE

```
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('lbo\User');
}
```

:: MODEL USER

```
public function employees(){
    return $this->belongsTo('lbo\Employee');
}
```

Na tabela **users** tenho o **employee_id**.
Preciso recuperar os funcionários (employee) que ainda não possuem usuários (user) criados.

Qual a melhor forma de se fazer a consulta?

Comment: Coloque todo o Model na pergunta não só a relação! e também faltou dizer se o campo da relação qual é o valor padrão quando não tem relação, que geralmente é deixado para receber valor `null`, mas, faltou dizer isso. Mesmo faltando algumas coisa resolvi postar uma solução

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Virgilio. Realmente a pergunta ficou incompleta. Como regra de negocio eu só consigo criar um usuário para um funcionário existente, isso me garante que nunca terei um employee_id na tabela users com o valor NULL. Lendo a documentação encontrei esta condição $employees = Employee::whereDoesntHave('users')->get(); que me atendeu bem.

Comment: Seguinte, eu editei a minha resposta, fiz a solução para as versões do Laravel e se for útil considere como resposta da sua pergunta. É bom creditar as respostas de quem está a te ajudar e isso serve de base para comunidade, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com [whereNotIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses), e o campo `employee_id` da tabela `users` quando não tiver relação, ou seja, `NULL` para funcionar:

***Exemplo:***

```
Employee::whereNotIn('id', function($q)
   { 
      $q->select('employee_id')
        ->from('users')
        ->whereRaw('not employee_id is null'); 
   })
   ->get();
```

Com o comentário do usuário, pela falta de informação (pergunta não clara) ele conseguiu resolver também com um método pronto [whereDoesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence), exemplo:

```
Employee::whereDoesntHave('users')->get();
```

e vale lembrar que muitas vezes a pergunta está mau formulada e *isso pode ser considerado como não clara que foi o que aconteceu*.

As duas soluções são viáveis a primeira para versões anteriores (`<=5.2`) que não possui esse método e a segunda para as mais atuais (`>=5.3`).

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)
- [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries)
- [Querying Relationship Absence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)